# Setting a height in Barplots for R

Tags: r

I bet this is incredibly simple, but I looked through the documentation on barplot() and could not find it.

I want to create a barplot, with a Y-axis of a particular height (lets say 4) even though the data only goes to 2. Is there some parameter I can pass so that this is done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be `ylim=c(0,4)` but it is hard to say without sample data.

```
R> vals <- c('a','a', 'b','b','a')
R> table(vals)
vals
a b 
3 2 
R> barplot(table(vals), ylim=c(0,4), main="Barplot with y-axis to 4")
R>
```

Comment: Perfect, worked great. I had tried the ylim parameter, but had no realized it needed to be a vector, rather than an int for the height.